# JPQL only returning the first record

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, jpql

Spring Boot/JPA/Hibernate/MySQL here. I have the following tables:

```
describe states;
+------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| state_id   | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| country_id | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| state_name | varchar(250)        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| state_code | varchar(3)          | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

describe countries;
+--------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| country_id   | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| country_name | varchar(250)        | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| country_code | varchar(3)          | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
+--------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

When I run `SELECT * FROM states WHERE country_id = 1;` I get:

```
+----------+------------+----------------------+------------+
| state_id | country_id | state_name           | state_code |
+----------+------------+----------------------+------------+
|     3805 |          1 | Alabama              | NULL       |
|     3806 |          1 | Alaska               | NULL       |
|     3807 |          1 | Arizona              | NULL       |
|     3808 |          1 | Arkansas             | NULL       |
|     3810 |          1 | California           | NULL       |
...
|     3860 |          1 | Virginia             | NULL       |
|     3861 |          1 | Washington           | NULL       |
|     3862 |          1 | West Virginia        | NULL       |
|     3863 |          1 | Wisconsin            | NULL       |
|     3864 |          1 | Wyoming              | NULL       |
+----------+------------+----------------------+------------+

(All 50 states)
```

That have the corresponding JPA entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "states")
public class State {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @JsonIgnore
    @NotNull
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "state_code")
    @NotEmpty
    private String code;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = [CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE])
    @JoinColumn(name = "country_id", referencedColumnName = "country_id")
    @NotNull
    @Valid
    private Country country;

    // Getters, setters & constructors
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "countries")
public class Country {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @JsonIgnore
    @NotNull
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "state_code")
    @NotEmpty
    private String code;

    // Getters, setters & constructors
}
```

I also have the following `CrudRepository`:

```
public interface StateRepository extends CrudRepository<State, Long> {
    @Query("FROM Province WHERE country = :country")
    public Set<Province> findAllByCountry(@Param("country") Country country);
}
```

Finally I have a service method that takes a `Country` and returns all the `States` that are associated with it:

```
public Set<Province> getProvincesByCountryCode(Country country) {
    log.info("Country id is " + country.getId());
    Set<Province> provinces = stateRepository.findAllByCountry(country);
    log.info("Found " + provinces.size() + " states associated with this country (" + country.getCode() + ")");

    // TODO: Return 'provinces' once I get this fixed...
    return null;
}
```

When this service method executes, it only returns a `List<State>` with a single `State` in it (so size is 1) and the log output is:

```
Country id is 1
Found 1 states associated with this country (US)
```

So the MySQL database is aware of all 50 states, but the `StateRepository` is only returning 1. Specifically its returning the first state record (Alabama), which I find interesting...

**Clearly something is wrong with my JPQL in the `CrudRepository`, can anybody spot what's missing?**

Comment: You are returning a `Set` which means you must have a proper implementation of the `equals` and `hashCode` methods. If those aren't properly implemented you will loose data in your `Set`. Instead try returning a `List` or `Iterable`. You also don't need the `@Query` as Spring Data JPA will generate it for you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but this didn't work.

Comment: What didn't work? There are multiple suggestions in there.

Comment: I changed the method to return a `List` instead and it still only returns the first record in the `states` table.

Comment: Also remove the `@Query` and change the method to `findByCountry` Spring data will do the rest. The `@JoinColumn` isn't needed. Nonetheless you should still implement a proper `equals` and `hashCode` for JPA (Hibernate) to work things out correctly especially with collections and caching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I just went with a native query:

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM states where country_id = " + countryId;
entityManager.createNativeQuery(query, State.class).getResultList();
```

Works like a charm!

Comment: Never you concatenation to build a SQL query! Also this isn't a solution but a hack/workaround.

Comment: Not without having a full picture. You ask a question with partial code and expect us to magically solve your issue. That obviously isn't going to happen. There were multiple suggestions, you tried one and stopped at it. You don't explain what you tried.

Answer (score 0):

Use folowing code:

```
public interface StateRepository extends JpaRepository<Province, Long> {
    public Set<Province> findAllByCountry(Country country);
}
```

Also the best way to debug this kind of stuff is enable sql logs in your app, see sql generated log, you can easily figure it out what's happing behind the seen

Comment: Thanks I tried your solution here and it did not work (same exact results).

Comment: have you seen the sql query log in your app?